# How can draw the line of linear regression on my original image in MATLAB?

Tags: matlab, linear-regression

I want to draw a red line on the edge of this image, I wanted to do that with the Linear Regression and I've already got the points of the edge and drawn the best line through the points on a graph, but I couldn't find out how to use the information to draw the same line on my original image.

[image]

```
Image = imread('55-1_a.jpg');

imshow(Image)

binary_Image = imbinarize(Image);

[PIC_X, PIC_Y] = size(binary_Image);

imshow(binary_Image)



% i creat a matrix with two columns and PIC_X-1 rows  
black_pixel_on_edge = zeros(PIC_Y , 2); % in each row i will save the lowest black point to use it later in the linear regression





 for k = 1 : PIC_Y % i go through the columns of the image
     black_pixel_on_edge(k, 1) = k;

     for k2 = 1000 : 2000% i o through the rows
         if( binary_Image(k2, k) == 0)%if the pixel is black i should save it in my array(WIDTH)

             black_pixel_on_edge(k, 2) = k2;
         end

     end



 end


 %draw all the points from my Matrix
 scatter(black_pixel_on_edge(:,1),black_pixel_on_edge(:,2));
  axis equal tight;


 h1 = lsline;% draw a line with linear regression
 h1.Color = 'r';


%save the data of the red line
 p2 = polyfit(get(h1,'xdata'),get(h1,'ydata'),1);


 Slope_Of_Line = p2(1, 1);
 Hight_Of_Line = p2(1, 2);

 % here i just want to draw the same red line on my original 'Image'
```

Comment: Use [`insertShape(...)`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/vision/ref/insertshape.html) if using R2014a or newer. Or simply [`hold`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/hold.html) your image and plot the line.

Comment: Thank you, in this case I also need to find out the start and end points of my line(h1), i don't know acutally how to do this. But my question is how to redraw the line "h2" once again on my picture. So can you help me with that?

Comment: It is not immediately clear to me where `h2` is supposed to be? Perhaps include a schematic photo to display lines `h1`, `h2`, etc so that it is more clear what you wanted to accomplish. "I want to draw a red line on the edge of this image" seems a bit unclear to me.